# Multi-core J -- Parallelisation

Tags: multithreading, vector, parallel-processing, j

Is there a way to get J to use multiple cores ?  I thought part of the benefit of APL/J was that the language constructs lent themselves well to parallel solutions.

Looking at my CPU usage (I'm on OSX) there's clearly only a single processor in use.

I've got a heavy-ish function f acting on a list, and I don't see why it couldn't divide the list into 4 pieces, and re-assemble the results ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but if you've written your solution in array-oriented way, you can run multiple instances of  your program for different segments of your arrays.

Comment: That's a pity.  Does any dialect of APL run multi-core ?

Comment: I ran into basically the same problem, so I took a bit more of a radical approach, I decided to write a compiler for a language that is basically J. The goals include multi-core support, GPGPU (CUDA/OpenCL) support, and the distribution of task over LAN. It is not finished yet, but you can keep up with the progress at https://github.com/Synthetica9/HyperJ

Comment: @Synthetica that's awesome. Will keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayFire may be worth looking into.  Its OpenCL with support for AMD/nvidia and backward fallback to CPU.  Its array processing.  It should bind easily to J, as it does in matlab.